# get title of sub site under variation in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I need to get the sub site name or the root site in sharepoint

Currently i am getting the title of the current page using

```
_spPageContextInfo.webTitle
```

This returns the title of the current page

Is there any provision like `_spPageContextInfo.parent____` or any other means using which i can get the title of the subsite under the variation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST Query to get the Title of web. Following is the function which will get the title of web.

```
function GetWebTitle() {
                try {
            //REST Query to get the display form url 
            jQuery.ajax(
            {
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web?$select=Title",
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    alert(data.d.Title);                    },
                error: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

                }
            });
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
}
$(document).ready(GetWebTitle());
```

Hope this help to solve your issue.

Comment: the data.d.title is returning the title of the current page
is there anything that i need to add to get the title of the root page?

Comment: this worked : changed the url!

Comment: Is there a way where i can do this without using ajax? 
I could find a way to get title if i use xmlhttp request